# Angular Unit test router.events

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a component that updates a variable on specific router events.  How do I unit test to make sure the code below works correctly?

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    this.isLoading = true;
  } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
    this.isLoading = false;
  } else if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
    this.isLoading = false;
    // console.error('effect error: ', error);
  }
});
```

Router stub

```
class MockRouter {
    navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');
    start = new NavigationStart(0, '/home');
    end = new NavigationEnd(1, '/home', '/dashboard');
    events = new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next(this.start);
      observer.next(this.end);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Follow up this [**link**](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-routed-component) you should be creating a router stub

Comment: I can get the router stub working but I am not sure how to get the isLoading variable to update

Comment: `return true or false` and check the component variable

Comment: Can you mock router.events with just a simple subscriber? No.

Comment: @bhantol so whats the hard way to do it?

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a simple Router stub to allow emitting various router events during the test.

Router stub:

```
// mocked source of events
const routerEventsSubject = new Subject<RouterEvent>();

const routerStub = {
    events: routerEventsSubject.asObservable()
};

describe('FooComponent', () => {
    ...
```

Then you simply use that stub:

```
...
let router: Router;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            {
                provide: Router,
                useValue: routerStub
            }
        ]
    });
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
...
```

A test looks like this:

```
it('should be loading on a navigation start', () => {
    // create a navigation event
    routerEventsSubject.next(new NavigationStart(1, 'start'));

    expect(component.isLoading).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Just an observation, why are we using let router = Router and router = TestBed.inject(Router); ?

Answer (score 4):

I was in a similar situation, and this is how I figured it out:

```
describe('router.events', () => {
  const mockStart = of(new NavigationStart(0, '/testUrl'));
  const mockEnd = of(new NavigationEnd(0, '/testUrl', '/testUrlRedirect'));
  const mockCancel = of(new NavigationCancel(0, '/testUrl', '/testReason'));
  const mockError = of(new NavigationError(0, '/testUrl', 'test error'));

  let routerEventSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    routerEventSpy = spyOn(component.router, 'events');
  });

  it('should set isLoading to true', () => {
    // Arrange
    routerEventSpy.and.returnValue(mockStart);
    component.isLoading = false; // initial value to make sure code is effective

    // Act
    // Call whatever method contains your router.events.subscribe - for example:
    component.ngOnInit(); // <-- Just an example, you should replace this with your corresponding method

    // Assert
    expect(component.isLoading).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should set isLoading to false for NavigationEnd', () => {
    // Arrange
    routerEventSpy.and.returnValue(mockEnd);
    component.isLoading = true; // initial value, see first test

    // Act
    // Call whatever method contains your router.events.subscribe - for example:
    component.ngOnInit(); // <-- Just an example, see first test

    // Assert
    expect(component.isLoading).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should set isLoading to false for NavigationCancel', () => {
    // Arrange
    routerEventSpy.and.returnValue(mockCancel);
    component.isLoading = true; // initial value, see first test

    // Act
    // Call whatever method contains your router.events.subscribe - for example:
    component.ngOnInit(); // <-- Just an example, see first test

    // Assert
    expect(component.isLoading).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should set isLoading to false for NavigationError', () => {
    // Arrange
    routerEventSpy.and.returnValue(mockError);
    component.isLoading = true; // initial value, see first test

    // Act
    // Call whatever method contains your router.events.subscribe - for example:
    component.ngOnInit(); // <-- Just an example, see first test

    // Assert
    expect(component.isLoading).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

A few notes:

- `component` should be replaced with whatever you store the `fixture.componentInstance` in.  It is the `this` in your tests.
- This would still work with a router like you have stubbed above, but it isn't using the `Observable` and its methods that you have declared - the `spy` is returning `of` observables to trigger the `subscribe`.  There's likely a way to use that Router Stub for your purposes ([e.g. @Yuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61654440/5365001)), but your question only asked for a way to test that logic and the `isLoading` variable.
- If your router is `protected` or `private` (a good practice), you can still spy on it with bracket notation - e.g. `spyOn(component['router'], 'events')`.